# Eclipse CDT crashing when trying to index header files

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm successfully cross compiling C++ code to run on a raspberyy pi from a Windows 7 machine through Eclipse Kepler SR1. Although the compilation is successful, there is a problem with the error parsing on the editor. It's showing red lines (errors) for functions/definitions such as cout, endl, string, etc.

When I click on Project->C/C++ Index->Search for Unresolved Includes I can see that  it complains that bits/c++config.h, bits/c++allocator.h and similar files are unresolved. So, I did a grep and found these and included the director under Project Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->Cygwin C/C++ Compiler->Includes and Eclipse just crashes. I noticed that it generates the attached log file. This seems like a nasty bug or a huge error on my part. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Here is the  [error log file](http://pastebin.com/jQxRGuxq).

Answer (score 1):

<sup>This answer not pretend to be a solution. Just a set of thoughts</sup>

There are many-many bugs in CDT. Try latest development versions in hope that someone fixed your issue.

Update sites (to install/update via `"Help"->"Install new software"->"Add..."` dialog):

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/luna/milestones (for Luna milestones)
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/builds/8.4/nightly (for 8.4 nighlies )

Or download directly from [CDT page](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php).

You can also check their [Bugzilla and forums](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/developers.php) if there are bug report for that issue and solutions/workarounds. And surely you can check out CDT source code and actively participate in bug fix ;)

Personally, I use latest milestones, because of indexer: 8.4 better understands C++11.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, this is better than nothing. Thanks I will try it out.